# Why SSRS 2005 PDF output UI is different

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have created reports (around 30 reports) using SSRS 2005 (BIDS) which include some charts and tables, the rendering out put for this reports is PDF and I have deployed this in my local machine server as well as some other SSRS server (client side server), the issue is when I get the output pdf file in the client side ssrs server it shows some UI issues like alignment, font, page braking , legend cut off  etc... but in my local environment its working fine (both local deployment and BIDS) and also all places we are using SSRS 2005,

Comment: Are the servers that you are seeing the problem on at the same version and patch level of SSRS? If so, I would next check to see that the same fonts are installed on all servers, or use commonly available fonts in the reports.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you will need to provide more and more specific information. What type and version report viewer are you using on either side? What are the specific UI issues? Can you isolate those issues one by one, preferably with reproducable scenario's? Are you *certain* it's the same report on both sides, with the same parameters and data set? Obviously *something* is different between the two sides, but we cannot know what this is: only *you* can find out and answer that question.

Comment: @JamieF It seems that the issue with the fonts, i have used the “Calibri” and it was not in the deployed server, so I put the “Calibri” font into the ssrs server machine but still its not getting applying, seems font size not applying.

Comment: This is resolved after put in the “Calibri” font into the ssrs server machine and restating SSRS server,